# iOS - heightForRowAtIndexPath does not fire during scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am writing a simple iOS app using Xcode4, which uses a table view to display a list of stories (fetched from a URL). I'm displaying the story titles as UILabels, and as a subview of the table cell.

I am over-riding `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to calculate the correct height for the cells according to the length of each story title. I'm adding the label to the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. When I run the app in the simulator, everything is rendered well. However: when I scroll down and scroll up, the labels get messed up. They get truncated and over-run. I debugged a little, and found that the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method is not fired during scrolling, so the cell heights are not re-calculated, and therefore the label text overflows, and gets rendered ugly. Here is the relevant code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        [cell autorelease];
    }

    /* NOTE: code to load trimmedTitle dynamically is snipped */
    NSString* trimmedTitle;

    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:14.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [trimmedTitle sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize 
                                    lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    UILabel* tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 0, 230, labelSize.height)];
    tempLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    tempLabel.text = trimmedTitle;
    tempLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:tempLabel];
    [tempLabel release];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString* cellText;  // code to load cellText dynamically is snipped off
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:14.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(230.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height + 20;
}
```

Comment: Probably you didn't set your delegate.

Comment: @Daniel: Can you please explain what you mean by that?

Comment: There are two "delegates" for a table view.  One contains cellForRowAtIndexPath and the other contains heightForRowAtIndexPath.  They can, of course, be the same object, but they must be set separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In situations like these I typically pre-calculate the heights of all of my rows, store them in an array, and then just returns those heights in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. This way the tableview knows the height of each cell and cells be conform to that height even after reuse. I don't know of a way to force a calculation of the cell height beyond looking for when a cell  will be viewable and reloading it, which seems too costly.

**Update**: some example code:

I have a method called `- (void)calculateHeights` which does the same calculation you had in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, but stores the result in my mutable array `heights_` ivar:

```
- (void)calculateHeights {
    [heights_ removeAllObjects]
    for (Widget *myWidget in modelWidgetArray) {
        NSString* cellText;  // code to load cellText dynamically is snipped off
        UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:14.0];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(230.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        [heights_ addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:labelSize.height + 20.0f]];
    }
}
```

And then in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, given a 1-section table view:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [heights_ objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
}
```

If your table view has more than one section you'll need to do some math to convert to the one-dimensional `heights_` array and back again. Also, any time you `-reloadData` you'll need to `-calculateHeights` as well.

Comment: If I take the approach of pre-calculating and storing the row heights, how do I then alter the height of the cell.. A little bit of sample code will be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The `-tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method is invoked before the scroll view is composed.

The purpose of calling this method before calling `-tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and not fired during the scrolling is that the table view (**Which is inherited from UIScrollView**) need to know the whole height of the contentView. Once the table view knows all the height, it cached the height before you call `-reloadData`

Your problem means you need to clear the content in the cell's `-prepareForReuse` and call `-setNeedLayout` to layout all the new contents.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **tag** for your label to avoid messed up to each other

```
UILabel *label= (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
```